# What are the names of 6 elements in Naruto?

Tags: naruto

I watched Naruto and saw a lot of elements that shinobis were using and I don't know the names of those elements because the subtitle I was watching Naruto with was not English. Do you know the names of 6 elements?. For example, Rikudou sennnin could use the 6 elements and what were the name of those 6 elements ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why this question got downvoted ? Please leave a comment while you're downwoting. Don't only downvote. And I don't know what is the problem with my question because of that there is no comment.

Comment: https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Nature_Transformation Have a go at it. It explains almost everything you want to know.

Comment: @RigaCrypto thanks very much. it told me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The chakra's basic nature releases are 5:
Fire (Katon), Wind (Fuuton), Electricity (Raiton), Earth (Doton) and Water (Suiton), reflecting probably the Buddhism's elements plus electricity.

Yin and Yang are too mentioned along the way, although they aren't really explained, but fundamentally they are the main components of chakra:
mental energy (Yin) and physical energy (Yang) unite to create the flow of chakra, some Shinobi are more skilled in some (like Nara clan's Shadow Possession techniques which use Yin release prevalently, or Akimichi clan's body expanding techniques which use Yang release) more than others.

Comment: Can we call Electricity element Lightning ? Is it Electricity or Lightning ?

Comment: While it's called lightning because it's based on the fact that ninja, in ancient times, could only think of the natural lightning as a concept for electricity (they didn't have computers like we see during the Anime), the chakra nature is created by molding chakra into electricity.

Bonus: Kakashi's Chidori is just a lightning release technique, it gets called Lightning Cutter (Raikiri) after he actually cut a lightning bolt from the sky and yadda yadda; Sasuke's ultimate electricity technique, Kirin, uses **actual** lightning, so it can be considered the only true lightning release.